Node platform exports during SSR
I have a package that declares platform exports in its package.json. I'm using the browser field to point to a entrypoint that is meant for use in browsers.
"exports": {
  "browser": "./index.web.js",
  "default": "./index.js"
}

I'm using RSPack to bundle my app for server side rendering. It has the concept of target like webpack but doing this means it no longer respects my exports.browser entrypoint, and instead picks a default that refers to packages that will not work in browser.
What is the tactic for building a server side rendering node server that consumes packages with browser exports?
